# Fixed (terrible mistake)! "Assertion `px != 0' failed." in a chat server using boost, std::map and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, server, assertion

I'm back with a new problem. I have to make a new version of the synchronous chat server using OOP. And I store the sockets in an std::map, in which the keys are the names of the clients and the values are shared pointers to ip::tcp::socket. Since I did it that way, I've been encountering the following problem:

I start the server and several clients. They write to each other successfully. However, if I close one of the connections, the server gets aborted that way:

```
server: /sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:687: 
typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type
boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = 
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>; typename 
boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = 
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
```

As I read about that assertion fail, it's something about uninitialized shared pointer. But I cannot find something like that in my code. Here's the codes:

server.h:

```
#ifndef SERVER_H_INCLUDED__ 
#define SERVER_H_INCLUDED__

#include<string>

#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

#include "common.h"

typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_ptr;

class Server
{
    boost::asio::io_service& service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;

    boost::mutex mtx;
public:
    Server(boost::asio::io_service& serv);
    void start();

private:
    void identify(socket_ptr sock);
    void writeMessage(const std::string& clientName, std::string& message);
    void notification(const std::string& clientName, const std::string headOfMsg, const std::string tailOfMsg);
    void disconnectClient(const std::string& clientName);
    bool readMessage(socket_ptr sock, std::string& message);
    void processLoop(const std::string& clientName);
};


#endif
```

server.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>

#include<boost/thread.hpp>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include<boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/unique_ptr.hpp>

#include "common.h"
#include "server.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

const string waitingMsg("Waiting for clients...\n");
const string totalClientsMsg("Total clients: ");
const int EOF_ERROR_CODE = 2;

map <string, socket_ptr> clientMap;

Server::Server(io_service& serv) : service(serv), acceptor(service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), PORT_NO))
{
}

void Server::start()
{
    cout << waitingMsg;
    while (true)
    {
        socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(service));

        boost::system::error_code error;
        acceptor.accept(*sock, error);
        if (error)
        {
            cerr << "Error on accepting: " << error.message() << endl;
            cout << waitingMsg;
            continue;
        }

        boost::shared_ptr <boost::thread> p (new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Server::identify, this, sock)));
    }
}

void Server::writeMessage(const string& clientName, string& message)
{
    mtx.lock();
    boost::system::error_code error;
    message.append(1, '\n');
    for(auto& cliSock : clientMap)
    {
        if (cliSock.second->is_open() && cliSock.first != clientName)
        {
            cliSock.second->write_some(buffer(message), error);
            if (error)
            {
                cerr << errorWritingMsg << error.message() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    mtx.unlock();
}

void Server::notification(const string& clientName, const string headOfMsg, const string tailOfMsg)
{
    string serviceMsg = headOfMsg + clientName + tailOfMsg;
    cout << serviceMsg << totalClientsMsg << clientMap.size() << endl;

    writeMessage(clientName, serviceMsg);

    cout << waitingMsg;
}

void Server::disconnectClient(const string& clientName)
{
    mtx.lock();

    boost::system::error_code error;
    clientMap[clientName]->shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error);
    if (error)
    {
        cerr << "Error on shutting: " << error.message() << endl;
    }
    clientMap[clientName]->close(error);
    if(error)
    {
        cerr << "Error on closing: " << error.message() << endl;
    }

    clientMap.erase(clientName);
    mtx.unlock();

    notification(clientName, "", " disconnected. ");
}

bool Server::readMessage(socket_ptr sock, string& message)
{
    mtx.lock();
    boost::asio::streambuf buff;
    boost::system::error_code error;
    size_t bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read_until(*sock, buff, '\n', error);
    if(error)
    {
        if (error.value() != EOF_ERROR_CODE)
        {
            cerr << errorReadingMsg << error.message() << endl;
        }
        return false;
    }

    buff.commit(bytes_transferred);
    istream istrm(&buff);

    getline(istrm, message);
    mtx.unlock();
    if(message + "\n" == "exit\n")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Server::processLoop(const string& clientName)
{
    while (true)
    {
        {
            string message = "";
            if (!readMessage(clientMap[clientName], message))
            {
                disconnectClient(clientName);
                return;
            }

            message.insert(0, clientName + ": ");

            writeMessage(clientName, message);
        }
    }
}

void Server::identify(socket_ptr sock)
{
    mtx.lock();
    sock->write_some(buffer("Please, enter your name:\n"));
    mtx.unlock();

    string name = "";

    boost::system::error_code error;
    bool occupied;

    do
    {
        if (!readMessage(sock, name))
        {
            return;
        }

        occupied = false;

        if (clientMap.find(name) != clientMap.end())
        {
            occupied = true;
        }

        if (occupied)
        {
            mtx.lock();
            sock->write_some(buffer("This name is already in use! Please, enter another name:\n"), error);
            mtx.unlock();

            if (error)
            {
                cerr << errorWritingMsg << error.message() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    while (occupied);

    mtx.lock();
    clientMap.emplace(name, sock);
    mtx.unlock();

    notification(name, "New client: ", " joined. ");
    processLoop(name);
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>

#include<boost/thread.hpp>
#include<boost/bind.hpp>
#include<boost/asio.hpp>
#include<boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

#include "common.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

io_service service;
tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string(IP), PORT_NO);

void displayLoop(socket_ptr sock)
{
    while(true)
    {
        {
            boost::asio::streambuf buff;

            boost::system::error_code error;
            size_t bytes_transferred = boost::asio::read_until(*sock, buff, '\n', error);
            if (error)
            {
                cerr << errorReadingMsg << error.message() << endl;
                continue;
            }

            buff.commit(bytes_transferred);
            istream istrm(&buff);
            string message = "";
            getline(istrm, message);
            buff.consume(buff.size());

            cout << message << endl;
        }
    }
}

void writeLoop(socket_ptr sock)
{
    string message = "";

    while(true)
    {
        getline(cin, message);

            message += '\n';

            boost::system::error_code error;
            sock->write_some(buffer(message), error);

            if (error)
            {
                cerr << errorWritingMsg << error.message() << endl;
                continue;
            }

            if(message == "exit\n")
            {
                exit(0);
            }

        message.clear();
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread_group threads;
    socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(service));
    boost::system::error_code error;
    sock->connect(ep, error);
    if (error)
    {
        cerr << "Error on connecting: " << error.message() << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Type \"exit\" to quit.\n";

    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(displayLoop, sock));
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(writeLoop, sock));

    threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H_INCLUDED__ 
#define COMMON_H_INCLUDED__

#include<string>

typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_ptr;

const unsigned PORT_NO = 30001;
const std::string IP = "127.0.0.1";

const std::string errorWritingMsg("Error on writing: ");
const std::string errorReadingMsg("Error on reading: ");

const std::string exitLower = "exit\n";
const std::string exitCapInit = "Exit\n";
const std::string exitCaps = "EXIT\n";

#endif
```

serverMain.cpp:

```
#include<boost/asio.hpp>

#include "common.h"
#include "server.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    Server server(service);

    server.start();
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
all: serverMain client

libraries = -lboost_thread -lboost_system 

server.o: server.cpp
    g++ -I/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/ $(libraries) -L/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/lib/ -c server.cpp -std=c++11 -lrt -ggdb

serverMain.o: serverMain.cpp
    g++ -I/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/ $(libraries) -L/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/lib/ -c serverMain.cpp -std=c++11 -lrt -ggdb

client.o: client.cpp
    g++ -I/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/include/ $(libraries) -L/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/lib/ -c client.cpp -std=c++11 -lrt

server.o: server.cpp
    g++ -c server.cpp -lpthread $(libraries) -L/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/lib -std=c++11 -lrt -ggdb

serverMain: serverMain.o server.o
    g++ -o serverMain serverMain.o server.o -lpthread $(libraries) -L/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/lib -std=c++11 -lrt -ggdb

client: client.o
    g++ -o client client.o -lpthread $(libraries) -L/sapmnt/HOME/i322722/usr/boost/lib -std=c++11 -lrt

clean:
    rm *.o serverMain client
```

The problem does not occur everytime I close a connection (sometimes if I want to close the first established connection, it's OK, however, the next one fails), but most of the times I have it. I think several times it occured while joining of new client but I'm not 100 % sure about that.

I think the problem is related to std::map and, more exactly, to the function

```
Server::disconnectClient(...)
```

in *server.cpp* but I'm not sure. Prior to intruduce this structure, everything worked fine, but there were separated std::lists for the sockets and for the names, which was bad. I have no idea where exactly is the problem and how to fix it. Every kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a threading issue. You should protect operations on `clientMap` with a mutex.

Comment: `clientMap[clientName]` would create default (empty) `shared_ptr` if key is not in map... You may use `clientMap.at(clientName)` instead...

Comment: This is not what "simple, selfcontained" means. Likely your shared pointers expire before you last use them (a close would remove pending async operations, meaning no binds hold refs anymore and objects gets deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry for wasting your time. Today I realized that such a terribly stupid thing had happened. The first version of the programs consisted only of server.cpp and client.cpp (and, of course, a makefile). In the makefile I compile the server and the client resulting in execute files "server" and "client". Since I switched to OOP version, the new execute files, produced by the makefile, have been "serverMain" and "client". However, I've been still calling "server" all the time until this morning, so it has been the old non-OOP version giving that weird assertion fail.

I'll keep the code here in case another errors occur. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (so the Q i marked as answered), and please remvoe the "fixed by now" from the title. In the future, consider reducing the problem to something smaller, each line of code you post reduces the likelihood someone will look at your code. good luck!